# Make Price Book Entry object's Product Code field Read/Write

Tags: product, pricebookentry, dataloader.io

I'd like to automatically create Standard Price Book entries for new products using dataloader.io.  I am successfully creating the new products, using the Product Code as the ID.  But when I go to create the corresponding price book entries, the upsert fails because the Product Code field on the Price Book Entry object is read-only.

I am trying to uncheck the read-only box on the Object Manager screen for Price Book Entry Fields and Relationships, but it appears hardcoded to be on.  Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to ask the people over at dataloader.io if there's a way to do this. Product Code itself is a "formula" on the Price Book Entry table, meaning it can be used to filter prices and display the code, but can't actually be inserted or updated as you're trying to do. If dataloader.io can't provide the sort of ETL service you need, you might need a specialty tool like Informatica or Relational Junction (specific product names should not be taken as an endorsement for those products; please do thorough research before making a purchasing decision). If you want to align the values yourself, you could export the Product2 table, and use Excel's VLOOKUP formulas to do the translation yourself.

Comment: I even tried to fake it by having a Product2Id column in my CSV with all values blank, and then making it a lookup field based on a value which was provided as an external ID.  They weren't fooled. :(  ERROR: 'Product2Id' ERROR:Required fields are missing: [Product2Id]"